# Как разделить массив char[] на несколько массивов с разной длиной?

Tags: java

Например, у меня есть массив:

```
char[] chars = {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'W', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd'};
```

и мне надо по определенной букве делить этот массив на части. В данном примере я хочу получить 3 массива `char` в одном массиве `MyString[]`.

```
char[] chars = {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'W', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd'};
MyString myString = new MyString(chars);
MyString[] arrX = myString.split('o');
```

Текущая реализация:

```
public MyString[] split(char c) {
    MyString[] arr = new MyString[3];
    int j = 0;
    int k =0;
    for (int i = k; i < chars.length; i++) {
        if (j < 3) {
            if (chars[i] == c) {
                char[] chars = new char[i - k];
                MyString myString = new MyString(chars);
                arr[j] = myString;
                k = i;
            }
        }
       j++;
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: символ разделить включать в массив или нет?

Answer (score 1):

Можно при нахождении заданного `char`-a в `chars` (а также при достижении конца массива) копировать `char`-ы из оригинального массива с индекса последнего нахождения до текущего (не включая границы), после чего в качестве индекса последнего нахождения указывать текущий. Начальным значением последнего нахождения будет `-1`.

Для удобства расчетов в коде сохраняется не текущий индекс, а текущий индекс плюс один. По этой причине начальным значением является `0`, а не `-1`.

Копируются `char`-ы в новый массив, из которого создаётся новый объект `MyString`, который затем добавляется в список. Используется список вместо массива, так как заранее не просчитывается сколько в результате будет объектов. В конце метода этот список преобразуется в массив.

```
public MyString[] split(char c)
{
    ArrayList<MyString> strings = new ArrayList<>();
    int lastFound = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= chars.length; i++)
    {
        if (i == chars.length || chars[i] == c)
        {
            char[] stringChars = Arrays.copyOfRange(chars, lastFound, i);
            strings.add(new MyString(stringChars));
            lastFound = i + 1;
        }
    }
    return strings.toArray(new MyString[strings.size()]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

У меня получилось такое решение:

```
public static List<char[]> split(char[] array, char delimiter) {
    List<char[]> result = new ArrayList<>();

    int next;
    int prev = 0;
    while ((next = getSubArray(prev, array, delimiter)) != -1) {
        result.add(Arrays.copyOfRange(array, prev, next));
        prev = next + 1;
    }

    if (prev < array.length)
        result.add(Arrays.copyOfRange(array, prev, array.length));

    return result;
}

private static int getSubArray(int start, char[] array, char delimiter) {
    for (int i = start; i < array.length; i++)
        if (array[i] == delimiter)
            return i;

    return -1;
}
```

Использовать так:

```
char[] array = {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'W', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd'};
char delimiter = 'o';

for (char[] part : split(array, delimiter))
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(part));
```

Вывод будет следующий:

> [H, e, l, l]
>   [ , W]
>   [r, l, d]

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял задание, то необходимо проделать следующее:

```
// исходная строка
char[] chars = {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'W', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd'}; 
MyString s = new MyString(chars);
MyString[] returnStrings = s.splitToArray('o'); // сюда мы запишем ответ

...

public MyString[] splitToArray(char c) {
  int counter = 0;
  // считаем все вхождения переменной c в строку
  for( int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++ ) {
    if( chars[i] == c ) {
      counter++;
    }
  }

  // если не нашли то выходим
  if (counter == 0) return null;

  MyString[] ret = new MyString[counter+1];

  int k = 0;
  int z = k;
  boolean found = false;
  for (int i = 0; i < counter+1; i++) {
    // теперь находим первое вхождение символа
    for(int j = k; j < chars.length; j++) {
      if( chars[i] == c ) {
        k = j;
        found = true;
        break;
      }
    }

    if (!found) k = chars.length;
    // создаем массив символов и перекидываем в него часть до интересующей нас буквы
    char[] charArr = new char[k-z];
    System.arraycopy(chars, z, charArr, 0, k-z);

    ret[i] = new MyString(charArr);
    z = k;
    found = false;
    k++;
  }

  return ret;
}
```

Естественно, если бы был имплементирован метод indexOf, то код был бы компакнее. 
К сожалению, код проверить возможности нет. Жду ваших ответных комментариев.

Comment: Цикл, в котором из chars перекидываются элементы в charArr, можно заменить на строку: Arrays.arraycopy(chars, z, charArr, 0, k);

Comment: @КириллМалышев сдаётся мне, что речь про `System.arraycopy`.

Comment: Ох, точно, спасибо!

Comment: Спасибо, что напомнили про `System.arraycopy`

Answer (score 0):

Решение при помощи строк:

```
char[] chars = {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'W', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd'};

String str = new String(chars);

String[] result = str.split("o");

char[][] resultInCharArray = new char[result.length][chars.length];

for (int i = 0; i < resultInCharArray.length; i++) {
    resultInCharArray[i] = result[i].toCharArray();
}
```